# Filter specific file type from the directory via C++

Tags: c++

I would like to print out specific file tpye(cpp,cxx,cpy...) in the directory via line#25 "if (file.cFileName[i - 1] ==(WCHAR)"." && file.cFileName[i] == (WCHAR)"c")"  for WCHAR comparison, but seems it's worked.
Does anyone have a idea about this?
Thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void FindFile(const std::wstring &directory)
{
    std::wstring tmp = directory + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(tmp.c_str(), &file);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> directories;

        do
        {
            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L"..")))
                    continue;
            }
            for (int i = 0; file.cFileName[i] != NULL; i++) {
                if (file.cFileName[i - 1] ==(WCHAR)"." && file.cFileName[i] == (WCHAR)"c")
                {
                    tmp = directory + L"\\" + std::wstring(file.cFileName);
                    std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;//print of the directory,endl->end line
                }
                }
            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                directories.push_back(tmp);
        } while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &file));

        FindClose(search_handle);
        for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = directories.begin(), end = directories.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
            FindFile(*iter);
    }
}

int main()
{
    FindFile(L"C:\\EF670610");
    cout << "Press Enter to continue " << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the loop from i=0 and perform a check to i-1, so this is a memory fault. You should start from i=1.

Comment: I have tried to revised the code from i=0 to i=1 but still not worked, I guess there's something wrong in the discriminant.